# Weak Convergence Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $X^*$ its dual space.
>
> a) If $\left\lbrace x_n\right\rbrace$ converges weakly to $x$ in $X$, then $\sup_n \|x_n\| < \infty$ and $\liminf_n \|x_n\| \geq \|x\|$
>
> b) If $\left\lbrace f_n\right\rbrace$ converges weakly-* to $f$ in $X^*$, then $\sup_n \|f_n\| < \infty$ and $\liminf_n \|f_n\| \geq \|f\|$

I believe I was able to prove the first part of $a$, but I'm not sure how to prove the second part at all. I know that since $x_n \rightarrow x$ weakly, then  for all $f \in X^*$, $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$. According to my notes from class (and we rushed through this part very quickly):

For every $x \in X$, there exists an $f \in X^*$ such that $\|f\|=1$ and $f(x) = \|x\|$ (why is this?). Then $\|x\| = f(x) = \lim_n f(x_n) = \liminf_n f(x_n) \leq \liminf_n \|f\|\|x_n\| = \liminf \|x_n\|$. Is that right?

For part $b$, is there a slick way to use the results from part $a$ to quickly conclude the results in part $b$?

Comment: I guess someone will tell you to use the [Hahn–Banach_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem) but what you'd like is to construct explicitely some $f \in X^*$ corresponding to the requirements ?

Comment: and for b) if $X$ is complete there is $x \in X, \|x\| = 1$ such that $|f(x)| = \|x\| \|f\| = \|f\|$ and $\|f\| = |f(x)| = \lim |f_n(x)| = \lim\inf |f_n(x)| \le  \lim\inf \|f_n\| $. if $X$ is not complete consider  its completion $\bar{X}$